# IronPython: Can't open Keil uVision .uvproj file edited with System.Xml

Tags: c#, ironpython, keil

I need to change some settings in Keil uVision project. I did not find how to disable/enable project options through command line.
So I tried to do this by simple parsing .uvproj and .uvopt files with System.Xml in IronPython:

import clr

clr.AddReference('System.Xml')

xml_file = System.Xml.XmlDocument()

xml_file.Load(PATH_TO_UVPROJ_FILE)

xml_file.Save(PATH_TO_UVPROJ_FILE)

The problem is that I can't open parsed .uvproj file in uVision (get error "Cannot read project file").
If I copy all text from parsed .uvproj and past it to newly created file (New-Text Document in Windows Explorer -> rename extnsion to .uvproj -> past copied text -> save file) uVision opens it without error.
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Could be problems with cr/lf.

Helpful would be a binary diff of the parsed and new created file. You could get more help if you post a few lines of a binary diff here.

Comment: No. cr/lf is not the problem.

Comment: Diff gives 0 differences. I still do not find the root cause of the problem but workaround is to create a new file instead of replacing existing.